# How do birds keep their heads in a fixed position, just like a Gyro/Gimbal?

Tags: birds, parrots

So I have a friend of mine with a redneck parrot. I noticed even if I move the bird in any direction his head remains in a fixed position.

Is this a common characteristics of all the birds or only in parrot family.?

Comment: this is common in birds they need to see where they are flying,have you seen the head of cats when they are running,that is just as impressive!

Comment: Thanks @Henders. They sure are impressive looking at the nature their head movements trond hansen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Its not just parrots.

Or Chickens

And pigeons bob their heads for the same reasons - unlike humans, who adjust their eyes to stabilise their vision, birds shift their heads - or as the [paper I'm looking at says](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/203/5/935.full.pdf)

> This has led to the view that the
>   pigeon’s head-bobbing is an optokinetic response to
>   stabilize the retinal image during the hold phase

Here's a pretty good article on the topic that I [vaguely referenced](https://io9.gizmodo.com/car-ad-perfectly-demonstrates-an-incredible-feature-of-1378832520)

Comment: Thanks @Journeyman Geek. It's amazing to see how nature has its own stabilization unit for our feather friends.

Comment: and that ticks off another thing in my "strange things I wish I I could use in an answer" list.